# preg_match matches only if it have "of" word or nothing

Tags: php, preg-match

I have 2 strings

```
"years of exp" & "years exp".
```

I want to match only above strings.

but not want to match string

```
"years sssss exp"
```

It only match if "of" word is between "years" & "exp" OR nothing between "years" & "exp".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?` quantifier, it means "zero or one".

```
"years (of )?exp"
```